# Embedding of $GL_n(F)$ inside another matrix groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

We can embed $GL_n$ inside $SL_{n+1}$ easily. is there any other such embedding of $GL_n$ or its subgroups inside any other group of invertible matrices?

Thanks in Advance.